# Bindings.isNotNull causes null pointer exception

Tags: java, binding, javafx

I have a simple field (well a property, really):

```
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<ObjectWithColor> colored;
```

The `ObjectWithColor` class has a property `SimpleObjectProperty<Color>`, hence the name.

Okay,now this property sometimes points nowhere; What I'd like to do is to have a `ObjectExpression<Color>` that returns `colored`'s color when not null, or  BLACK otherwise.

I wrote this code in the constructor:

```
colored = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();  
ObjectExpression<Color> color= Bindings.when(colored.isNotNull()).then(colored.get().colorProperty()). otherwise(Color.BLACK);
```

What I don't understand is why I get a **NullPointerException** running that line of code. I understand that gets called, but I don't understand why. Shouldn't that be called only when colored is non null?

Comment: Without providing more details about the source code, one can only guess what is happening.

Obviously, any of the when(), then(), otherwise(), get() or colorProperty() methods could be returning null. I would start from the latter two.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*> Shouldn't that be called only when colored is non null?*

No. Lets do some analogy with your code:

```
SimpleObjectProperty<ObjectWithColor> colored = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();  
colored.get().colorProperty();
```

Since the `Property` and its derivative classes are all wrapper ones, it can be thought as a Person class having (wrapping) fullName field as String. So the analogy for the above:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.getFullName().toString();
```

We get NullPointerException at getFullName().toString(), since getFullName() returns null.

For both comparisons the assumption was; the wrapped field does not has a default value or does not initialized in the default constructor.

Lets continue with this assumption. In this case we can avoid NullPointerException by,
initializing value through constructor:

```
Person person = new Person("initial full name");
person.getFullName().toString();
```

or calling setter:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setFullName("Foo Bar");
person.getFullName().toString();
```

The same is true for your code:

```
SimpleObjectProperty<ObjectWithColor> colored = 
                     new SimpleObjectProperty<>(new ObjectWithColor(Color.RED));  
colored.get().colorProperty();
```

or

```
SimpleObjectProperty<ObjectWithColor> colored = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
colored.set(new ObjectWithColor(Color.RED));
colored.get().colorProperty();
```

I hope I have understood your question correctly. Nevertheless, on other hand, in a "Shouldn't that be called only when colored is non null?" prompt, you are talking about colored is non null while you actually checking for `lastSupplier.isNotNull()`. I presume it as **not** a typo and answered based on current code piece.

---

**EDIT: Ohh! It was a typo then!**
Was able to generate the problem. As  a documentation of `javafx.beans.binding.When#then()` mentions, this method returns:

```
the intermediate result which still requires the otherwise-branch
```

Thereby the statement `colored.get().colorProperty()` must be reachable. Normally the bindable if-then-else block was designed for the usages like:

```
SimpleObjectProperty<Double> doubleProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty();
ObjectExpression<Double> expression = Bindings.when(doubleProperty.isNotNull()).then(doubleProperty).otherwise(-1.0);
System.out.println(doubleProperty.getValue() + "  " + doubleProperty.isNotNull().getValue() + "  " + expression.getValue());
doubleProperty.setValue(1.0);
System.out.println(doubleProperty.getValue() + "  " + doubleProperty.isNotNull().getValue() + "  " + expression.getValue());
```

Output:

```
null  false  -1.0
1.0  true  1.0
```

As a result, you may define an initial default value:

```
SimpleObjectProperty<ObjectWithColor> colored = new SimpleObjectProperty(new ObjectWithColor(Color.BLACK));
```

or may use ObjectWithColor.colorProperty in bindings directly.

Comment: Thanks, actually the reply clarified a lot BUT that was a typo in writing to stackOverflow. My problem is that even when I say colored.isNotNull() the bidings go read colored.getColorProperty().get() which throws a NullPointerException. It's really very annoying

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks. I was using Bindings.select... but I really disliked that.